# XSL 3 match text() where self is the first sibling of a specific node

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

In this XML:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="MS609-1577">
    <teiHeader/>
    <text>
        <body>
            <ab xml:id="MS609-1577-LA" xml:lang="la">
                <seg type="dep_event" subtype="denial" xml:id="MS609-1577-1" sameAs="#MS609-1553"><lb break="y" n="24"/>Item. 
                <date type="deposition_date" sameAs="#MS609-1553" xml:id="MS609-1577_depdate">Anno <supplied>et die</supplied> predictis</date>.
                    <persName ref="#peire_guibert_asv-hg" role="dep">Petrus Guitberti</persName> 
                    testis juratus dixit idem per omnia quod 
                    <persName ref="#peire_bernart_asv-hg" role="ref">P<supplied reason="abbr-name">etrus</supplied>
                        Bernardi</persName>.<seg type="witnesses" sameAs="#MS609-1601"/></seg>
            </ab>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

I would like to move the full stop from outside the element `<date>` to the position of last child inside the element `<date>`. So, this fragment:

```
<supplied>et die</supplied> predictis</date>.
```

becomes:

```
<supplied>et die</supplied> predictis.</date>
```

...while everything else should be copied intact.

The following XSL puts the full stop into the required element as the last child.

However, the third template is applying the `substring()` to all `following-sibling::text()` of `<date>`. I only want to target the first `following-sibling` only in the case where it is a `text()` node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="tei:date[@type='deposition_date' and ./following-sibling::node()[1][. instance of text() and starts-with(.,'.')]]">
        <date xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
          <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="./(* | text())"/>
          <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </date>
  </xsl:template>
  
   <xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(.,'.')][./preceding-sibling::tei:date[@type='deposition_date']]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFbBTu6/1

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for the third template would be

```
<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(.,'.')][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::tei:date[@type='deposition_date']]]">
```